# How to integrate the authentications of MEAN Stack into Ionic app?

Tags: rest, authentication, ionic-framework, mean-stack, json-web-token

I have previously asked the question, how to use the authentication of the MEAN boiler plate to Ionic app. After some digging, I found out that MEAN boiler plate has a cookie based session system and it's not possible to create a REST API using sessions. I have managed to change the authentication system to JWS. How should I now use the authentication of the MEAN app in my IONIC application?

P.S: I am successful in getting JSON data from other Restful API endpoints I have created in my application.

Comment: Hi , Umair Sarfraz i  am using passportjs for authentication in server side and also used in client side by calling **REST API**

Comment: @AnuragPandey Do you have a web application as well or only ionic app with backend?

Comment: @AnuragPandey Can you share with me the authentication API and their calls from backend to ionic?